# Connotation of "maze" and "get maze"?

Tags: word-choice, connotation

Is it correct to say "get maze"? If so, what's the meaning?

Also, does "maze" have a bad connotation?

Comment: Are we talking about _maze_ the noun, or _maze_ the verb? Also where did you here "get maze"?

Comment: maze the noun. but I'd like to know what comes to your mind when you read it.

Comment: In what context?  I would have thought "maze" was pretty much neutral unless there is a context to suggest whether it is good or bad.

Comment: Nothing comes to my mind. Well, my mind auto-corrected it into “get mazed”, actually (see my answer below).

Comment: Perhaps "get maize" as an advertisement, promoting this as an alternative to rice or something...

Comment: Googling tells me that "Get Maze" is advise to get a certain app (called Maze) for my computer or cell phone.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can **get mazed**, which means “get confused”:

> verb (be mazed): archaic or dialect —
>   be dazed and confused: *she was still mazed with the drug she had taken*.

(from the *New Oxford American Dictionary* for maze). But you cannot **get maze** anymore than you can **get labyrinth**: it doesn't fit grammatically, whether *maze* is the noun or the verb.

Comment: Does "get maze" have any grammar mistake? thanks

Comment: @donald: it's not that it has grammar mistakes, it is much that one can't make any sense of it. What are you trying to say?

Comment: Yes -- it should be "get mazed" if you're going to use it at all. Using it at all, though, is probably not a good idea -- it would be like using *stonied* instead of *astonished*. It works perfectly if you want to write in the style of Mallory's *Morte D'Arthur*, but a vanishingly small number of modern readers would be able to derive any meaning from it.

Answer (score 3):

> Also, "Maze", does it have a bad connotation?

Not by itself. It depends how it is used.

> There is a fine maze at Hampton Court.

Is positive.

> His mind was like a maze

Isn't.

Answer (score 1):

If you are talking about a physical maze that you can hold in your hands (such as one printed in a "solve the maze" book) then you could say "get the maze", as in "I got the maze from this book."

Alternatively, if you're looking at a maze of any size and you want to express that you understand the method by which the maze was designed or can be solved, you could say "I get the maze", using 'get' in the sense of *comprehend*.

In both cases, the definite article is required to indicate that you are talking about a specific maze.

Beyond that, no likely interpretations of "get maze" come to my mind.